# Washing Pesach: kohanim

Tags: passover, korban, book-of-chronicles, ezra-nechemya

In preparation of the Pesach I read a couple of verses from the Tenach and found something which raised a couple of questions. In  [Divrei Hayamim II 35:6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Chronicles.35.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) for example I found that the Levites should ***sanctify*** themselves in order to slaughter the animal as a Pesach offering.

In [Ezra 6:19](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezra.6.19?lang=bi) the Levites are described as being tahor; they purified themselves; where ritually clean in order to slaughter the animal as a Pesach offering.

Questions:

1. What's the difference between sanctify and purify in order to slaughter the offering for Pesach?
2. Is this done by or related to the washing like Aharon and his sons were washed (once) and later had to wash their hands and feet ([Shemot 30:19](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.30.19?lang=bi&aliyot=0)) in order to sancify themselves before HaShem and in order to purify themselves; be made ritually clean in order to offer?

Comment: Are you asking about Levites or Priests?

Comment: The text in Divrei Hayamim II 35:6 reads "And slaughter the Passover sacrifice and sanctify yourselves" which seems to mean that the slaughter preceded the sanctification.

Comment: 1. Probably not, but see Malbim to Ezra. 2. It refers to purifying from various kinds of spiritual impurity, each one according to its rules as laid out in Leviticus.